# Is it possible to type a TS class method that isn't an arrow function?

Tags: typescript

Below is a very simplified example of what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to use one method definition to define another method definition.  I can do it just fine if I turn the method into an arrow function, but I can't figure out any syntax to type it when it's not an arrow function.  Is this possible?

```
class A {
    doThing(x: number, y: string) { return 123; }

    doThingAndReturn42: typeof A.prototype.doThing = (...args) => {
        this.doThing(...args);

        return 42;
    }

    // Is it possible to type this like the above method?
    doThing2AndReturn42(...args) {
        this.doThing(...args);

        return 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you have to split up the parameter and return types.

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#22063](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063) for the relevant feature request

Answer (score 1):

Closest you can get is using the helper types `Parameters` and `ReturnType`:

```
class A {
    doThing(x: number, y: string) { return 123; }

    doThingAndReturn42: A['doThing'] = (...args) => {
        this.doThing(...args);

        return 42;
    }

    doThing2AndReturn42(...args: Parameters<A['doThing']>): ReturnType<A['doThing']> {
        this.doThing(...args);

        return 42;
    }
}
```

Note that it's simpler to write `A['doThing']` instead of `typeof A.prototype.doThing`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oBMD2AVAFgJYB2A5gBQAeAXNMQK4C2ARgKYBOANNAJ60QAXdiVIBKRNHasB9dsWgBGAEwBmANzQAvqlQYseImVjFMAJWmziAFiW1YAbQDkOAiMcBdaAF5o5AHQBYOykEOJeAHyIunoYAkQQfi6GFAF+QSGiajpoMehSMnLQNlk56Noo0ehJIkrGZhZyNv6BwRC0AApBYIzSHBAAPA7OBm7u4aK05gXEuDwADqyDTtVkHpHIpTFxhAkrKS0ZJZUx+ZZFSiV65ZpAA)